# How to style an Avalonia DataGridRow via data binding to a view model row

Tags: datagrid, avalonia

I am using a `DataGrid` control in Avalonia and I want to apply styles to `DataGridRow` based on data binding to the view model backing a row. How can I do this?

I figure it will be based on classes, so I defined a style for an `isRequired` class:

```
<DataGrid Items="{Binding Players}">
  <DataGrid.Styles>
    <Style Selector="DataGridRow.isRequired">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Styles>
</DataGrid>
```

But notice the class is supposedly going to be set on a `DataGridRow`, but how can I set that class on the row based on a bound `Player` view model?

Answer (score 1):

In WPF I'd often reach for `Trigger`s but I've started to employ more `Converter`s lately.

```xml
<DataGrid.Styles>
    <Style Selector="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Tag, Converter={StaticResource OrderRowBackgroundConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Styles>
```

```cs
public class OrderRowBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            switch (value.ToString())
            {
                case "":
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Color.Parse("#FF8D8D"));
                case "fulfilled":
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Color.Parse("#B8FFB8"));
            }
        }
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.Parse("#FF8D8D"));
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```